# Sufficient/Necessary condition to have Fourier series representation.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let $g :\partial\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ where $\partial \Omega$ is unit circle. Let $h(\theta)$ be the polar form of $g(x,y)$. What is the condition on $g(x,y)$ to assure that $h(\theta)$ has fourier series representation?

This is actually from a partial differential equation, $$\nabla^2 u(x,y) = 0\qquad x^2 + y^2 < 1$$ with boundary condition $$u(x,y) = g(x,y)\qquad x^2 + y^2 = 1.$$

I can solve the problem, but the Prof didn't say anything about $g(x,y)$. This makes me unsure with steps I did in solving the PDE.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not strictly related, but I assume you are solving $\Delta u(x,y) = 0$ on $x^2 + y^2 < 1$, right?  Otherwise, the only solutions are constants.

Comment: @strants ah yes, I forgot the square.

Comment: $g$ has to be (Lebesgue) integrable on the unit circle